# Ruby PayPal Permissions SDK Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using this gem stated in the title: https://github.com/paypal/permissions-sdk-ruby

I got everything to work, but it seems the gem only has built-in methods that request basic and advanced user info. However, I need to get transaction/payment data. What's the best way to go about this?

Do I use the tokens to now make requests manually via HTTParty or such?

paypal.yml

```
test: &default

  # Credentials for REST APIs
  client_id: AZeKLB9rkwMumoPHGg_xG-sMOtEREDh3VeSP2cgbdorScFDkGBAoG2WQ0ZNtIgdKM6eaCfYqKmXzxDqS
  client_secret: ELXfwfA4wGU_PEwjIiYllCvs7gQCYsaWyN_yzXux5XSrHv6ZxGEUasnSIHvkAZ4-rYXTcvC4Igy097xo

  # Mode can be 'live' or 'sandbox'
  mode: sandbox

  # Credentials for Classic APIs
  app_id: APP-80W284485P519543T
  username: jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com
  password: WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F
  signature: AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy
  # # With Certificate
  # cert_path: "config/cert_key.pem"
  sandbox_email_address: kolbywebdev-facilitator@gmail.com

  # # IP Address
  # ip_address: 127.0.0.1
  # # HTTP Proxy
  # http_proxy: http://proxy-ipaddress:3129/

development:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
  mode: live
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK) ? This gem provides methods that help you make payments, get payment details and a lot more.

Comment: I did see that but I didn't realize I could use that the same way, to allow users to authorize with a button and then I can access their payments. Thank you! I will try it out.

Comment: Yup, that gem should serve all the requirements that you're looking for. You can always comeback here, if you run into any issues.

Comment: I don't see any resources for authorization. @KedarnagMukanahallipatna

Comment: Turns out I needed both gems, I have it working now.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna actually, I was mistaken. I'm stuck and not sure where to go from here. Can you help? I'm using both gems but when I try to pull payments, it's pulling the payments from my App's sandbox account, not the account that I authenticated with.

Comment: Sure. Can you share the configuration you have done ? `paypal.yml`

Comment: Sure, added it to the original post. I did not change any of the "Credentials for Classic APIs" other than the sandbox_email_address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179877/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-kolbykskk).

Answer (score -1):

this gem has been deprecated, so you had better move to REST API or JavaScript SDK. https://rubygems.org/gems/paypal-sdk-rest you can see deprecation

Comment: Please share the source to describe your answer. This doesn't prove anything.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35772407)